# Krakenuniq mmap error

Tags: metagenome

I built Krakenuniq on an HPC, and I've been trying to run it on my data using the following command:

```
krakenuniq --db DBDIR --threads 1 All_reads.fastq
```

This definitely isn't powerful enough to get any reasonable output, but this is just a test run. However, I got the following error:

```
classify: unable to mmap ./DBDIR/database.kdb: Invalid argument
```

I haven't been able to find anything about this error online. DBDIR is 1TB, which seemed huge, so I was wondering if there might have been a problem with the build, but I saw no issues in the log.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is DBDIR in your working directory? Did you perhaps mean to write `--db ${DBDIR}`?

Comment: That's not how it's done in the documentation, and in any case it causes its own error:

Comment: `krakenuniq: unable to find --threads in $KRAKEN_DB_PATH (undefined)` DBDIR appears to be in the working directory (ls lists it there).

Comment: I have run into the same issue with the default Kraken using a prebuilt database at the university HPC.

Comment: @schmiggle Did you ever find a solution to this? I can see the database file (for example, ./DBDIR/database.kdb) is there, but I get the same error.

Comment: I switched to using Kraken2 instead because of issues like this. Didn't ever find a solution.